# Converting a Column in a Dataset into a list of Entities

Tags: entity

I have created a dataset that contains a column of countries in one column and a list of values in a second column. Please could someone advise me how to convert the countries into entities whilst preserving the whole dataset so that I can then use the data to call the function GeoRegionValuePlot.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. Could you please load a few rows of your data in copy-paste-able form. Press `Edit` under your post and select directly from the notebook cell using Ctrl-C. Paste using Ctrl-V in the `Edit` window. There is a `{  }` icon there to format it as code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) several ways to that. You should be able to "just" use:

```mathematica
Append[#, 
 "CountryEntity" -> 
  Entity["Country", 
   StringReplace[#Country, WhitespaceCharacter -> ""]]]
```

But that does not always work.

Here is a more robust way:

**1.** First we make name-to-entity association:

```mathematica
aCountries = Association[#["Name"] -> #1 & /@ CountryData[All]];
lsCountries = Keys[aCountries];
```

**2.** We obtain (generate) country name and value dataset:

```mathematica
SeedRandom[45];
dsRand =
 ResourceFunction["RandomTabularDataset"][{12, {"Country", "Value"}}, 
  "Generators" -> {lsCountries, NormalDistribution[120, 4]}]
```

**3.** We add a new column using the name-to-entity association:

```mathematica
dsRand[All, 
  Append[#, "CountryEntity" -> aCountries[#Country]] &] // Normal
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your very quick response. I will try your suggestions.